# AWS Elastic load balancer doesn't decrease instances from Alarm Trigger

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-elb, amazon-cloudfront

I have a load balancer that I created an auto-scaling-group and launch-config for.
I created the auto-scaling-group with a min-size of 1 and max size of 20.
I have a scaledown policy:

```
    as-put-scaling-policy SBMScaleDownPolicy --auto-scaling-group SBMAutoScaleGroup --adjustment=-1 --type ChangeInCapacity --cooldown 300
```

Then I set up an alarm:

```
    mon-put-metric-alarm SBMLowCPUAlarm --comparison-operator LessThanThreshold --evaluation-periods 1 --metric-name CPUUtilization --namespace "AWS/EC2" --period 600 --statistic Average --threshold 35 --alarm-actions arn:aws:autoscaling:us-east-1:policystuffhere:autoScalingGroupName/SBMAutoScaleGroup:policyName/SBMScaleDownPolicy --dimensions "AutoScalingGroupName=SBMAutoScaleGroup"
```

When average CPU usage over 10 minutes is under 35, in CloudFront the alarm shows up as "In Alarm State" but doesn't decrease the number of instances. Also, if there's only one instance running it'll spin up another to 2 even if a scale up alarm isn't hit. It seems like the default value is just set to 2 somehow. How can I change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.
I had manually added the first instance to the load balancer. After removing that one everything functioned as expected.

Answer (score 1):

A likely cause is that you are more than one Availability Zone enabled, and it is ensuring there is at least 1 instance in each zone.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your auto scaling group *SBMAutoScaleGroup* is not quite configured as desired - have you double checked the outcome of [CreateAutoScalingGroup](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AutoScaling/latest/APIReference/API_CreateAutoScalingGroup.html)? See example 7 within section *Command Line Tools Example* on page [Auto Scaling with Alarms and Load Balancing](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_SetUpASLBApp.html) for an easy way to do this:

```
as-describe-auto-scaling-groups SBMAutoScaleGroup --headers
```

The resulting table should show the desired values for *MIN-SIZE*, *MIN-SIZE* and *DESIRED-CAPACITY*.

Likewise you might want to verify that the policy has been attached correctly:

```
as-describe-policies SBMAutoScaleGroup
```

The resulting table should list your auto scaling policy *SBMScaleDownPolicy* with the desired values for *ADJUSTMENT*, *TYPE* and *COOLDOWN*.

A possible reason why `as-put-scaling-policy` might have failed is mentioned in example 5 within section *Command Line Tools Example* on page [Auto Scaling with Alarms and Load Balancing](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_SetUpASLBApp.html), which stresses a specific requirement when using the Windows command line:

> If you are using Windows, wrap the --adjustment parameter in quotation
>   marks: "--adjustment=-1".